# Find the maximum of $(\cos\theta +1)(\cos\phi +1)-(\sin\theta + \sqrt{3})(\sin\phi + \sqrt{3})$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, vectors, maxima-minima

If I could find the MAXIMUM of following, I'll finish some problem concerned with vector inner product.

$$(\cos\theta +1)(\cos\phi +1)-(\sin\theta + \sqrt{3})(\sin\phi + \sqrt{3})$$

If the CONSTANTS are ZERO, then

$$\cos(\theta+\phi)$$

SO, the maximum will be 1.

but in this case... HOW DO I modify ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by taking the partial derivative of the expression ($E$), and the result is
$$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial  \theta} = -\sin{\theta} (\cos{\phi} +1 ) - \cos{\theta}(\sin{\phi} + \sqrt{3}) = -\sin{\left( \theta + \phi \right)} - 2 \cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{6} - \theta \right)}
$$
Since $E$ is symmetric for $\theta$ and $\phi$, you only need to solve for the zeros of this equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is

$$ f(\theta,\phi) =  \cos(\theta+\phi) - 2\sin\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) - 2\sin\left(\phi-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) - 2 $$

Taking the partial derivatives

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta} = -\sin(\theta+\phi) - 2\cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\phi} = -\sin(\theta+\phi) - 2\cos\left(\phi-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) $$

Both have to be $0$, so it follows that
$$ \cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \cos\left(\phi-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) $$

Here we have two scenarios

- $\phi-\dfrac{\pi}{6} = \theta - \dfrac{\pi}{6} + 2n\pi \implies \phi = \theta + 2n\pi $
- $\phi-\dfrac{\pi}{6} = \dfrac{\pi}{6} - \theta + 2n\pi \implies \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{3} -\theta + 2n\pi$

---

If $\phi = \theta + 2n\pi$ then
$$ \sin(2\theta) + 2\cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 0 $$

There are two solution sets

- $\theta = -0.574 +2m\pi$, where $f = 1.971$
- $\theta = 1.837 + 2m\pi$, where $f = -6.730$

---

If $\phi = \dfrac{\pi}{3} -\theta + 2n\pi$ then
$$ \sin \frac{\pi}{3} + 2\cos\left(\theta-\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = 0 $$

You don't need to solve this, as 
$$f\left(\theta,\frac{\pi}{3}-\theta\right) = \cos \frac{\pi}{3} - 2 = -\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me absorb your answer..