# Vector with circles

Tags: real-analysis, vectors

> Let  $O_1$ , $O_2$ , $O_3$  be a circle of radius $1$.
>
> Each of $O_1$ , $O_2$ , $O_3$  meet the others.  (Please see figure)
>
> Let
>
> P : the point of circle $O_2$
>
> Q : the point of circle $O_3$

[image]
$$$$

In this case,

**

> What is the maximum of $\vec{O_1 P} \cdot \vec{O_1 Q} $  (inner
>   product)

**

$$$$

I've struggled this for hours

and I get [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749977/find-the-maximum-of-cos-theta-1-cos-phi-1-sin-theta-sqrt3-sin-p/2750030#2750030)

$$$$

But this is for high school students not for university ...

How do I deal with this....?

$$$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hint: $xy$ has the maximum when $x=y$ so consider the case when magnitudes of both vectors are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial, but it can be done.

Step one: let's fix the position of $Q$, and for now choose $O_1Q$ as the $x$ axis of the coordinate system, such that $O_1$ is at $0$. The dot product that you want to maximize in this case is $O_1Q$ (fixed) multiplied with the $x$ coordinate of the $P$ point. You can now calculate the $x$ position of the $P$ point, as the $x$ coordinate of the $O_2$ plus $1\cdot\cos\theta_P$. The first part does not depend on $\theta_P$, so the maximum is achieved when $\theta_P =0$, or in geometric terms $O_2P||O_1Q$.

Step two: repeat the same procedure by fixing $P$, to obtain $O_3Q||O_1P$.

Step three: since the above conditions are independent of each other, the maximum is achieved when both are true. Let's calculate the coordinate of $P$ and $Q$. For simplicity, use the coordinate system with the $x$ axis starting at $O_1$ and perpendicular to $O_2O_3$. If you extend $O_2P$ and $O_3Q$, they intersect the $x$ axis at the same point $O_4$, forming a parallelogram $O_1O_2O_4O_3$, with $O_1O_4$ as one of the diagonals. The  other diagonal intersects the $x$ axis at point $M$. So you have $O_1O_2=2$, $O_2M=1$, therefore $O_1M=\sqrt{3}$. By symmetry, the $x$ coordinates of $P$ and $Q$ are $\frac{3}{2}O_1M=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{3}$. Also by symmetry, you can get the $y$ coordinates as $\pm\frac{1}{2}$.

Step four: $$\vec{O_1P}\cdot\vec{O_1Q}=x_Px_Q+y_Py_Q=\frac{\sqrt{27}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{27}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{-1}{2}=\frac{26}{4}$$

That's if I did not make any errors :)

Comment: Thank you very much. After working, I'll read with appreciation.